# How to contextually respond to keyboard input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

**Example here**: https://jsfiddle.net/ngecpjb9/

When **N** is pressed, the next Vue component is chosen. However, when typing in an input element, if I hit **N**, it "chooses" the next component. This should be disabled when focused on an `input`.

My Vue app has hundreds of components in a hierarchy several layers deep, is there a standard pattern or library for separate components accepting keyboard input?

Comment: and if you add a condition like no input are selected (with a state for example that is set to true when a input is active)  in your onKey method ?

Comment: @antoineso Yes, that would work, but this was only a reproduction. For example, if I have three components that are in the same hierarchy, but each one has a completely different keyboard mapping... I'm trying to figure out how to abstract it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the focused element with `document.activeElement`, and if it is an text input, i.e. `input` `textarea` or `contenteditable`, just ignore the key, like this:

```
const onKey = (e) => {

    const inputs = ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'];
    
    const isInput = document.activeElement === e.target &&
      (inputs.includes(e.target.tagName) ||
      e.target.hasAttribute('contenteditable'));
      
    if (!isInput && e.code === 'KeyN') {
        active.value = (active.value + 1) % 3;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could validate in your `onKey` method if the target has a `type`, since only input tags have type attribute

```js
const onKey = (e) => {
  if (e.target.type !== undefined && e.code === 'KeyN') {
    active.value = (active.value + 1) % 3;
  }
};
```